Поисковая строка и вывод товаров по нему Django
я новичок в Django, делаю сайт доску объявлений. Появилась проблема с поиском. При вводе названия товара в поиск и нажатии enter ничего не выводит.models.py
class Products(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.TextField()
    images = models.TextField()

views.py
from .models import Products
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector, SearchQuery, SearchRank
from django.views.generic import ListView


class ProductsSearchResultView(ListView):
    model = Products
    context_object_name = 'articles'
    paginate_by = 10
    allow_empty = True
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('do')
        search_vector = SearchVector('title', weight='B') + SearchVector('description', weight='A')
        search_query = SearchQuery(query)
        return (self.model.objects.annotate(rank=SearchRank(search_vector, search_query)).filter(rank__gte=0.3).order_by('-rank'))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = f'Результаты поиска: {self.request.GET.get("do")}'
        return context

def index(request):
    prods = Products.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', context = {
        'prods' : prods
        })

urls.py
from test_app import views
from test_app.views import ProductsSearchResultView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('index.html', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('search/', ProductsSearchResultView.as_view(), name='search'),
] 

index.html
<form role="search" method="get" action="{% url 'search' %}">
<input type="search" placeholder="Поиск" aria-label="Search" name='do' autocomplete="off" id="search">
</form>


